# python ipmitool reboot issue in Linux

Tags: python, ipmitool

here is the thing, I created a txt file with string used python first, so far, everything is normal. then used ipmitool to reboot, but the txt file is empty when OS boot up.

```
with open('test.txt','a+') as f:
 f.write('test')

os.system('sudo ipmitool chassis power reset')
```

I have no idea how this happened, is there any possible reasons may cause this?
BTW, if manually execute ipmitool, it's normal too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `sync` command before `ipmitool chassis power reset`. It will flush buffers to permanent storage.

```
sync; ipmitool chassis power reset
```

Comment: See also [`os.fdatasync`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fdatasync)